# GoogleCloudStorage make redirect to another domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Thanks in advance for your answers I want to make google cloud storage links (storage.googleapis.com) to redirect to my own domain I've achieved that so far but when I add something like a picture that is hosted in one of my servers which is linked to this domain the google cloud storage link does not function well, explanaition :

For example my domain name `example.com`, which is linked to my google cloud account with this link https://storage.googleapis.com/example-test/example.html if I add anything after that like https://storage.googleapis.com/example-test/example.html#gOAdv.png it only redirect to the main domain `example.com`

This is the content of my `example.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0; url=http://myexampledomain.com/">
```

Note when I remove the # from the link (https://storage.googleapis.com/example-test/example.html#gOAdv.png)
it shows this error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Details>No such object: example-test/example.html/gOAdv.png</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hello everyone i ve found the answer it was my way of thinking

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0; url=http://myexampledomain.com/">
```

this line was short and bad i needed to code it via another language to make it work.
Thanks to all.

Comment: What did you do exactly? This line is exactly the line in your question.